# promise all with list

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-promise

I'm trying to use promise all with two list, and I'm not getting the desired values:

With only one list it works:

```
this.firstService.getAll()
  .then(dataR => {
      //dataR = ['data':{'data1': 'one-one', 'data2': 'one-two'},
      //   'data':{'data1': 'two-one', 'data2': 'two-two'}]
      return Promise.all(
        dataR.data1.map(x =>
          this.secondService.getReadURL(
            x.one))
    }
  ).then(dataR2 => {
     //dataR2 is a list of strings
  });
```

Now I'm trying to add a second call in promise with data2:

```
 return Promise.all(
        [dataR.data.map(x =>
          this.secondService.getReadURL(
            x.data1)),
        dataR.data.map(x =>
          this.secondService.getReadURL(
            x.data2))]

    }
  ).then(dataR2 => {
     //dataR2 is a list of list of zoneAwarePRomise
  });
```

How can I get lis of list of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, Promise.all accept an array of promise `[promise]`, but you are sending `[[promise],[promise]]`.

```
var promises = dataR.data.map(x =>
    this.secondService.getReadURL(
        x.data1));

promises = promises.concat(dataR.data.map(x =>
    this.secondService.getReadURL(
        x.data2)));

return Promise.all(promises).then(data => {});
```