# Get array elements outside the foreach loop in node js

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

Hi I have 2 collections in mongo db and I need to retrieve some results from one collection based on certain conditions from another one.

I am taking _id field from my 1st collection based on some conditions and I am getting an array of objects _id's. Am looping this array and try to taking results from second collection that matches with this _id.

The result from second array is another array of objects. Like below,

```
[
 {
  portfolio: [
   [Object], [Object],
   [Object], [Object],
   [Object], [Object],
   [Object], [Object]
 ],
 _id: 603e0129e879ce0954caf7b9
 }
]
[
 {
 portfolio: [
   [Object], [Object],
   [Object], [Object],
   [Object], [Object],
   [Object], [Object]
 ],
_id: 603e0147e879ce0954caf7ba
 }
 ]
```

I need to push these portfolio arrays to another empty array. Below is the code I used.

```
public async bestCall() {
    let currentdate = this.checkTime();
    currentdate = currentdate.substring(0, currentdate.indexOf(' '));
    let updateData: Array<String> = []; //this is the array to which I need to push my result elements
    var records = await this.sc.find({ conDate: { $lte: currentdate }, conEnd: { $gte: new Date(currentdate) }, conTypeId: 2 }, { _id: 1 });
    records.forEach(async (element) => {
        let result: any = await this.pf.find({ stContestId: element._id }, { portfolio: 1 });
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            await (result[i]['portfolio'].ticker).map(async (value: any) => {
                updateData.push(value)
            })
        }
    });
    console.log(updateData) //this is empty
}
```

Portfolio is an Array of objects:

```
 "portfolio":[
   {"sn":{"numberInt":"0"},
   "sector":"Communication",
   "ticker":"TEST",
   "logo":"https://xxx",
   "x":{"numberInt":"0"},
   "i":{"numberInt":"0"},
   "p":{"numberInt":"0"},
   "cp":{"numberInt":"0"},
   "cpp":{"numberInt":"0"},
   "ind":{"numberInt":"0"}} ]
```

I tried it with mongo db lookup using the following code, but failed. The result only gives me the data of inout collection not the portfolio from 2nd collection:

```
var res: any = await this.sc.aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                $and: [{ "conDate": { $lte: currentdate }, conEnd: { $gte: new Date(currentdate) }, "conTypeId": { $eq: 2 } }

                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "pf",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "stContestId",
                as: "portfolio"
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "portfolio": 1
            }
        }

    ]);
    for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        console.log(res.length)
        console.log(res[i])
    }
}
```

Result is pushing to updateData array inside the loop, but am not getting it outside the foreach loop. How can I get it outside the loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [promise all with list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49251323/promise-all-with-list)

Comment: It's rather suboptimal poetry =). You make a request to the database from within the loop. You can employ [aggregation lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to do it on mongo side and retrieve whole array in a single query.

Comment: in sample data, you have portfolio: [], but in your code you access .ticker. what is the form of portfolio ?

Comment: @AlexBlex I have added the lookup code that I tried.

Comment: @grodzi I have added portfolio array sample.

Comment: Your aggregation works perfectly fine if I reverse-engineer your documents from it https://mongoplayground.net/p/xSpE56zUHe0